# How much do i need to learn in order to get an entry level asp.net job?

Tags: web-development, learning, c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If you develop with ASP.NET, which other technologies do you use?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66389/if-you-develop-with-asp-net-which-other-technologies-do-you-use)

I'm currently learning C#, but I've noticed that there is a lot of demand for ASP.NET developers.

I purchased the book 'Beginning ASP.NET 4: in C#' by Wrox. I will start with that book and finish the web project provided in the book after I've learned C# fully.

I wanted to know how much C#, SQL, CSS, XHTML, Javascript and/or jQuery I need to learn in order to have a chance of getting an entry level ASP.NET job.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a good litmus test:

- Can you build a ***cookbook application***?

At its core, a cookbook application is a CRUD application. This means it includes web pages which:

- **C** reate data.
- **R** ead data.
- **U** pdate data.
- **D** elete data.

To do this (without an out-of-the-box CMS of course ;), you must implement a fair amount of C#, SQL, XHTML, and CSS. This would be a good start.

Once you can build a cookbook application, reflect a little bit more. Can you build an *attractive* cookbook application? That is, can you build an application which is both aesthetically pleasing and very usable?

To do *this*, you must implement a fair amount of javascript and/or jQuery.

If you can do *this*, then you are most certainly ready to interview for an entry-level ASP.NET position.

And when preparing for the interview, be ready to discuss your experience putting together the "cookbook application".